# How to count how many times each file was modified in git?

Tags: git

I am working on a real mess of a project and we've been planning to refactor it for months but nobody has the time.
I want to see which files are most modified because the features/codes contained in those files will have the priority on refactoring and increasing my productivity.

Is it possible to get number of times each file was modified since first commit or a specific week, in a table format or something, in git? If so, how?

Comment: This is usually called a "churn metric", see [this command for an example](https://github.com/garybernhardt/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/git-churn).

Comment: After 6+ years, I thank you nonetheless, Lord Lasse V.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To count the number of commits for each of 
your files, you could do something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.php;
do
echo $file
git log --oneline -- $file | wc -l
done
```

"git log" is the key git command here.

Here are some git commands and options to look at

```
git log 

git log --oneline
```

To get a log of changes for a specific file

```
git log -- filename
```

To get a log of changes for a specific file
during a specific date you can do

```
git log --after="2017-05-09T16:36:00-07:00" --before="2017-05-10T08:00:00-07:00" -- myfile
```

You may want to try

```
git log --pretty=format
```

you can look up all the different formats

You could get a private repository on github
and push it all up there; that would be a
nice graphical way to see all the changes
for any of your changed files.